# Decrypt encrypted files (AES CFB8) in iOS

Tags: ios, encryption, cryptography

I need to decrypt files that are encrypted with openssl as follows:

```
 openssl enc -d -aes-256-cfb8  -nopad  -in myFile -iv myIV -K myKey
```

Specifically the iv and key are array of bytes. Example (in hex):

```
key: 5492557823faec274708eb34d263029084abe5544789340a1d3ccf6bd74774ad
iv: 01e2a0ac72375edec4b126b1197a2885
```

How can I do that?

I tried to follow the example here [AES/CFB8 IV size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600277/aes-cfb8-iv-size) but with scarce results.

EDIT:

Here's what I tried already:

```
NSString *IVString = @"3d090e3f7a72d51ae4f4d0d15025926e";
NSString *KEYString = @"207ecf137586424952b8cfc3e7fd8ce9bd839a916c07b9d5f34d250315d91aa9";


NSData *myIV = [IVString decodeFromHexidecimal];
NSData *myKey = [KEYString decodeFromHexidecimal];

CCCryptorStatus result = CCCryptorCreateWithMode(kCCDecrypt,
                                                 kCCModeCFB8,
                                                 kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                                 ccNoPadding,
                                                 [myIV bytes],
                                                 [myKey bytes],
                                                 kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                                 NULL,
                                                 0,
                                                 0,
                                                 0,
                                                 &_cryptor);

size_t *outLength;

NSMutableData *cipherData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:self.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];

if (result == kCCSuccess)
    result = CCCryptorUpdate(_cryptor,
                             [self bytes],
                             [self length],
                             [cipherData mutableBytes],
                             [cipherData length],
                             outLength);

if (result == kCCSuccess)
    result = CCCryptorFinal(_cryptor,
                            [cipherData mutableBytes],
                            [cipherData length],
                            outLength);
if (result == kCCSuccess)
    result = CCCryptorRelease(_cryptor);
```

EDIT 2:

Thanks Rob, that helped me out!

Final code:

```
CCCryptorStatus result = CCCryptorCreateWithMode(kCCDecrypt,
                                                 kCCModeCFB8,
                                                 kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                                 ccNoPadding,
                                                 [myIV bytes],
                                                 [myKey bytes],
                                                 kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                                 NULL,
                                                 0,
                                                 0,
                                                 0,
                                                 &cryptor);


size_t bufferLength = CCCryptorGetOutputLength(cryptor, [self length], false);
NSMutableData *buffer = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:bufferLength];

size_t outLength;


result = CCCryptorUpdate(cryptor,
                         [self bytes],
                         [self length],
                         [buffer mutableBytes],
                         [buffer length],
                         &outLength);


result = CCCryptorRelease(cryptor);
```

Comment: See https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor

Comment: do you have an example on how to use a mode different than CBC with RNCryptor?

Comment: Please show us what you tried and how it went wrong, you are currently showing scarce results for sure.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-owlstead I updated the original question with my code.

Comment: @Zaph unfortunately it's not my choice, that's how the server was developed.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at an old .h file, CFB8 mode is supported. Pass `keykCCKeySizeAES256` for key size and ensure your key is 32 bytes in length and that the iv length is 16 bytes. The values you show are Base64 encoded and need to be decoded to data, data is best displayed in hex. Provide hex dumps of the key, iv and data in, data out for both success and failure. The data needs to be an exact multiple of the block size (16 bytes) if padding is not used.

Comment: @rmaddy, RNCryptor isn't any help here. The RNCryptor format isn't compatible with OpenSSL, and my OpenSSL-compatible code is all about dealing with OpenSSL's key generation, which this code doesn't require.

Comment: @Zaph I updated my code in the question. I don't get errors during the decryption, and I can see bits of the original file if I open it, but it's still not readable. I guess I'm on the right path but I'm missing something.

Comment: @Zaph you mentioned that I need to make sure that the key is 32 bytes in length. After some test I noticed that it takes a while to decrypt large files. I tried to pass a 16 bytes key but it won't work (I changed key size in the CCCryptorCreateWithMode call too). It works if I give the openssl command to decrypt it. Is there a reason behind it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `cipherData` as the buffer, but you don't create any space in it. (You also use the same buffer in the update and final steps without unloading the result, so that can corrupt your result, though you might get away with it in this case because there's no padding). (EDIT: I started writing this a few hours ago; I see you've changed you code since then to allocate the buffer, but you're still reusing it, which is what's going to corrupt your result. I also see you switched from encrypt to decrypt. Note that then your result is not "cipherData" anymore.)

First create your cryptor (this part is right, though there's no reason to put it in an ivar):

```
CCCryptorRef cryptor;
CCCryptorStatus result = CCCryptorCreateWithMode(kCCEncrypt,
                                                 ...
                                                 &cryptor);

// FIXME: Return error
if (result != kCCSuccess) { NSAssert(@"Failed to create cryptor: %d", result) }
```

Then figure out how big your buffer has to be:

```
size_t bufferLength = CCCryptorGetOutputLength(cryptor, [self length], true);
```

Now create a buffer:

```
NSMutableData *buffer = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:bufferLength];
```

Setup your output variables:

```
size_t outLength;
NSMutable *cipherData = [NSMutableData data];
```

Process the data:

```
result = CCCryptorUpdate(cryptor,
                         [self bytes],
                         [self length],
                         [buffer mutableBytes],
                         [buffer length],
                         &outLength);

// FIXME: Release cryptor and return error
if (result != kCCSuccess) { NSAssert(@"Failed to encrypt: %d", result) }
```

Copy what we have so far into our final result (see note):

```
[cipherData appendBytes:buffer.bytes length:outLength];
```

Finish up (since there's no padding, this might not do anything, but it is necessary in the general case):

```
result = CCCryptorFinal(cryptor,
                        [buffer mutableBytes],
                        [buffer length],
                        &outLength);

// FIXME: Release cryptor and return error
if (result != kCCSuccess) { NSAssert(@"Failed to finalize: %d", result) }
```

If we got anything append it, and do final cleanup

```
[cipherData appendBytes:buffer.bytes length:outLength];

result = CCCryptorRelease(cryptor);
if (result != kCCSuccess) { NSLog(@"Failed to do final cleanup, ignoring: %d", result) }
```

And that should be it.

Note that there are ways you could rework this so you don't have to copy your ciphertext, by moving the buffer pointer forward between the update and the final, but unless it's a lot of ciphertext, I'd just do it the simple way and make a copy.

Comment: thank you for your precious help. Yesterday I kept working on my code and I didn't realize I pasted the wrong snippet at the beginning. My goal is to decrypt a file more than encrypt it. So what do you mean that the result is not cipherData anymore? where would it be stored?

Comment: so yes, eventually I commented out the CCCryptorFinal, and it worked like a charm. The thing that I guess made it work was the initial CCCryptorGetOutputLength. Thank you so much.